# asp.net-iis7 concurrent requests

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am developing Rest web service using ASP.NET and IHttpHandler module. By default concurrent requests is not allowed, new request is not proceeded until previous is finished from the same user. I would like to increase concurrent request for the same user to three(3). How to do that? Is that possible to control from web.config file?

Comment: How did you determine ASP.NET does not process requests concurrently by default?

Comment: I call IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest and no other connection is accepted until first request is finished. So answer would be: By testing.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET does, in fact, support concurrent requests per user. You just need to disable Sessions where you want to allow the concurrent requests.

If you use sessions in your services, you'll need to figure out an alternative if you want to support concurrent requests.

Comment: How to do that for ASP.NET HttpHandler application?

Comment: Just to clarify, even with Sessions enabled, ASP.NET allows concurrent requests as long as they are all different sessions.  It logically "single-threads" all requests from Session123, but will still concurrently process a request from Session456.